# Datatables left join linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, join, dataset

I'm having a hard time joining 2 datatables and have the joined datatable
as result.

First datatable (labels) holds data including a printerid.
Second datatable (printers) holds printer references (id > unc)

I would like to have as endresult (joined) a datatable with all data
from the first datatable with the field (unc) of the second datatable.

This is what i have been trying: (mind that fixed paths are for convenience...)

```
Sub Main()

    Dim ds1 As new DataSet

    ds1.ReadXml("C:\Program Files (x86)\[COMPANY]\ASW2XML\BICOLOR_a07bfc62-501e-4444-9b6e-3b9d3550e1a4.xml")

    Dim ds2 As New DataSet

    Dim li As string()

    li = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Program Files (x86)\[COMPANY]\ASW2XML\printers.dat")

    Dim printers As New DataTable("Printers")

    printers.Columns.Add("REPRT2")
    printers.Columns.Add("REPRT3")

    For Each s In li.ToList

        Dim dr As DataRow = printers.NewRow

        dr.Item(0) = s.Split("=")(0)
        dr.Item(1) = s.Split("=")(1)

        printers.Rows.Add(dr)

    Next

    printers.AcceptChanges

    Dim labels As DataTable = ds1.Tables(0)

    Dim joined As new DataTable("data")

        'Dim lnq = From label In labels.AsEnumerable Join printer In printers.AsEnumerable On label("REPRT") Equals printer("REPRT2") Select printer
        'Dim lnq = From l In labels Group Join p In printers On l Equals p("REPRT2") Into Group From p In Group Select label = l, ppath = If(p Is Nothing, "(Nothing)", p("REPRT3"))
        Dim lnq = labels.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(o)printers.Select("REPRT2 =" & o.Item("REPRT").ToString).Length = 0)

        joined = lnq.CopyToDataTable


End Sub
```

Thx for your help and inspiration!

grtz -S-

Comment: You should not hard-code `C:\Program Files`.  There are people who do not have `C:` drives.

Comment: I copied my code from a service project to have easier access to try this code and hardcoded the path to 2 files because in the service they are dynamic. I need the "magical" key only and then put this linq query.copytodatable in my service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to do it the "hard" way and loop through all rows in parent table.
This goes very fast for a minor amount of records, I don't know if running this on
a larger amount of records speed will greatly decrease over using a Linq solution...

This is the code that I'm using atm:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim ds As new DataSet

    ds.ReadXml("C:\Program Files (x86)\[COMPANY]\ASW2XML\BICOLOR_a07bfc62-501e-4444-9b6e-3b9d3550e1a4.xml")

    Dim labels As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
    Dim printers As DataTable = GetPrinters

    labels.Columns.Add("REPRT2").SetOrdinal(labels.Columns.IndexOf("REPRT")+1) 'insert new column after key column
    labels.CaseSensitive=False
    labels.AcceptChanges

    For Each dr As DataRow In labels.Rows

        Dim p As String = String.Empty

        Try
            p = printers.Select("ID='" & dr("REPRT") & "'")(0).Item("PATH").ToString
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        dr("REPRT2") = p

    Next

    labels.AcceptChanges

End Sub

Function GetPrinters As DataTable

    Dim printers As New DataTable("Printers")

    Dim li As string()

    li = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Program Files (x86)\[COMPANY]\ASW2XML\printers.dat")

    printers.Columns.Add("ID")
    printers.Columns.Add("PATH")

    For Each s In li.ToList

        Dim dr As DataRow = printers.NewRow

        dr.Item(0) = s.Split("=")(0)
        dr.Item(1) = s.Split("=")(1)

        printers.Rows.Add(dr)

    Next

    printers.AcceptChanges

    Return printers

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join.aspx

Make your datatables as an extension of IEnumerable (like list as you did) and a join in linq would make it work easily.

then send the joined tables to any destination you want.

Comment: Can you provide an example applied on my code above please? :)

Comment: @grmbl: I moved an example to a post.

Answer (score 1):

I thought a comment would be harder to understand so I moved it in a post.

I wrote a bit of strucure that shoud help you understand how Join works:

```
structure Label
    Public printerId as long
    Public driver as Strring
end structure

structure Printer
    Public unc as string
end structure
```

If you set Labels and Printers to DataTable (instead of the structures below), you shoud have something like :

```
 function DoJoin() as datatable 
    'You might remove as datatable in query declaration
    dim query as datatable = Labels.Join(Printers, Function(aLabel) aLabel, _
    function(aPrinter) aPrinter.unc, _
    function(aLabel, aPrinter) New With  
    { .printerID = aLabel.printerId, .driver = aLabel.Driver, _
      .unc = aPrinter.unc
    })
    return query 
end function
```

However I wote it this morning in notepad, so you might have to adjust this. I just want to add that you must have the same type of container in order to use join (eg : example in [Join at msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx) they used 2 Lists.), that are compatible with Linq obects (datatable I do not know).